# TCL puts stream: Can I know what stream is? stdout? stderr? file?

Tags: tcl

For complicated reasons I have to hijack the "puts" routine.  I would like to do different things based on what "stream" is

```
proc myPuts { stream msg } {

      if < stream is stdout >
          ....
      elseif < stream is stderr >
           ...
      else
           ...

}
```

Is there some way to know if the stream argument is stdout, stderr or a file from inside TCL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the stdout stream in Tcl is "stdout", and stderr is "stderr".  If one does a `puts $stream "string"` with $stream having a value of "stdout", it goes to stdout; similarly with stderr.

The normal call to `puts` treats the stream argument as optional; your myPuts will need to do the same, and treat a missing operand as stdout.  Beyond that, I believe it's just a matter of

```
if {$stream eq "stdout"} {
    # do your stdout thing
} elseif {$stream eq "stderr"} {
    # do your stderr thing
} else {
    # do your file handle thing
}
```

Comment: For string comparisons, use `eq` instead of `==` -- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm#M14